# Can one make OrmLite's dao.create to insert a null value to an int field instead of 0?

Tags: java, mysql, null, ormlite

Is it possible to make `dao.create()` insert `null` into a default null integer field instead of 0?

The `canBeNull` argument of the `@DatabaseField` annotation defaults to true anyway according to the docs and I'm yet to find a way how to feed `null` value as a `defaultValue` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make dao.create() insert null into a default null integer field instead of 0?

Yes, you can do that.

> I'm yet to find a way how to feed null - value as a defaultValue - argument.

By default, any uninitialized field should be assigned that type's default value in the database.  For example, an `int` field with no value set on it when the entity is created should get a value of 0 in the database.  With any *object* field (such as `Integer`) the default value is already `null`.  All you need to do is to *not* provide a `defaultValue`.

For example the following code works for me:

```
public class Foo {
     @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
     private int id;
     @DatabaseField // no default-value specified
     private Integer someIntegerField;
}
...
Foo foo = new Foo();
// leave someIntegerField as a null value without a default-value defined
assertEquals(1, dao.create(foo));

Foo result = dao.queryForId(foo.id);
// by default the field that we did not initialize comes back as null
assertNull(result.someIntegerField);
```

If you provide a default-value then ORMLite is going to try to convert it to an integer value so it can assign it.  Just remove the default-value setting and it should work.

Comment: Yes, just don't use primitive types and then you can set `null` for nullable types.